# JRuby generated java class -> Jar

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have a Ruby script, I want to make it into a Jar file.

Using JRuby, I have compiled my script and now have a `*.class` file.

How do I now convert my `*.class` into a `*.jar` file so that it can be be executed through a JVM?

Thanks.

Edit:
"Main-Class: HelloWorld

"

(basically manifest.mf is Main-Class: HelloWorld followed by two new lines.)

Answer (score 2):

It is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

for example:

```
jar cf C:\hi.jar C:\classes\hi.class
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but it then says `no main manifest attribute, in blah.jar` when I run it.  So then when I create a manifest file and compile with `cvfm` parameter, it says `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror`.

Comment: try this:<br>
jar cfe hi.jar MainClass *.class<br>
jarfile name, mainclassname without extension, class files to add.

Comment: Same problem as before: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`...

Comment: MainClass is the class in which the main method is.
for example if your main method is in hi.class then replace MainClass with hi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20435/discussion-between-selim-and-user968243)